# How do I check if a string exists within a string within a column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, any

What I want to do I figured would look like this:

```
(t in df[self.target]).any()
```

But I am getting:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'
```

Comment: `(t in df[self.target])` returns a boolean object, `True` or `False`, for whether or not t is in that iterator.

Comment: Please post an example DataFrame.

Comment: Is `self.target` a column in the DataFrame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Pandas `str` methods ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains)).

```
df[self.target].str.contains(t).any()
```

Comment: This is the pandas way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's a pandas DataFrame. Try this

```
(df[self.target] == t).any()
```

EDIT:

```
any((t in k for k in df[self.target]))
```

Comment: This returns True if there is an exact match "foo" == "foo", but will not catch the case where "foo" in "foobar".

Comment: edit: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'any'